# How to switch to a running program when closing a tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sapui5, sap-gui

Currently I log in SAPGUI via Portal. I have ABAP program which opens a link to UI5 application (creating a new tab in the same browser window with the Portal).

There is a requirement that by closing the UI5 application tab, ideally the SAPGUI window will pop up and user should go back to SAP GUI to continue original transaction. Consider adding a footer to the UI5 app with a button to “Close” which will close the tab.

Is it possible to handle "going back to SAPGUI" from javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no. Thanks good, that is impossible. Imagine if every webpage could access your desktop in any way.

You can use [SAPGUI shortcuts](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/SAPGUI+shortcuts) to open a new transaction via file download.
Just set up every browser as open download per default and trigger a  SAPGUI shortcut via button.